# Including QgsRasterBandStats in plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm making a plugin were i want to get the min and max value of a raster. When i tried the following code in the qgis python console it worked fine but in my plugin code i get the following error

```
 ver = provider.hasStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All)
 NameError: global name 'QgsRasterBandStats' is not defined
```

The code i m using is:

```
    layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
    renderer = layer.renderer()
    provider = layer.dataProvider()
    extent = layer.extent()

    ver = provider.hasStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All)

    stats = provider.bandStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All,extent, 0)

    minum= stats.minimumValue
    maxim = stats.maximumValue

    self.dlg.lineEdit.addItems(minum) 
    self.dlg.lineEdit_2.addItems(maxim)
```

It look like QgsRasterBandStats isn't included in my python plugin. How can i include this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import it in this way in the header of the corresponding Python file:

```
from qgis.core import QgsRasterBandStats
```

If you have other classes being imported from `qgis.core`, you can list them:

```
from qgis.core import class1, class2, ..., QgsRasterBandStats
```